# Django: ModelForm custom error message and placeholder

Tags: django, forms, placeholder, django-forms

I'm running into an issue of only being able to have either a custom error message OR placeholder text. As soon as the custom error message is added into the ModelForm the placeholder text is no longer showing— order does not effect result. Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

```
class LetterForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
       model = Letter
       exclude = ('date_submitted', 'read', 'approved', 'post', 'date_post', 'url', 'tags',)
       widgets = {
        'youtube': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'youtube'}),
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'name'}),
        'location': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'location'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email'}),
    }
    name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Don\'t want to share your real name?'
                                                       ' Just enter Anonymous.'})
```

Comment: Just a shot: would this work? name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Don\'t want to share your real name?, Just enter Anonymous.'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'name'})

Comment: @karthikr yup! I actually just figured it out prior to your post. Thanks for the heads up though. Respect.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I'll just leave this here for anyone that might interested

```
name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'message'},
                       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))
```